# How to choose integers within a range that have some difference between them?

Tags: combinatorics

I have to find out the number of selections of two integers from 1 to 100 such that all of them have a difference of 7. There are C(100,2) = 4950 ways to select two integers within this range. How does one find the number of selections that have a difference? For example 8-1 = 7, 9-2 = 7. How can this be combined to find out the combinations?

Hint: The answer is 93.

Comment: How many ways are there to pick the smaller number? Once you do that, how many ways are there to pick the bigger number?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $n$ and $n+7$ be such numbers then
$$1\leq n<n+7\leq 100.$$
What is the range for $n$?